# GridView RowDataBoundEvent not running

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, tableadapter

I'm working with a GridView and I am using a TableAdapter to communicate with my SQL Server 2017 Express. I have managed to display the table into a GridView but I would like to make the name of each entry in my database have a hyperlink that will direct the user to another page that contains a DetailsView that would allow the user to edit the corresponding entry. However, I am currently have troubles with the RowDataBoundEvent as it seemingly is not triggering.

When I set a breakpoint right at the if statement, the program [does not stop at the breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45162920/gridview-rowdatabound-not-running-code).

```
protected void ProductViewRowBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string hyperLink = e.Row.Cells[1].Text;
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Test";
        //HyperLink link = new HyperLink;
    }
}
```

I checked my RowDataBound method name and it matches the one I specified in the aspx file:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ProductView" runat="server" Height="299px" Width="578px" AllowPaging="True" HorizontalAlign="Center"
    OnRowDataBoundEvent="ProductViewRowBound" style="table-layout:auto">
    <HeaderStyle Width="300px" />
</asp:GridView>
```

CS File:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;


public partial class Maintenance : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            ProductSetTableAdapters.Product_Table_AlphaTableAdapter productAdapter = new ProductSetTableAdapters.Product_Table_AlphaTableAdapter();
            ProductView.DataSource = productAdapter.GetData();
            ProductView.DataBind();
        }

        ProductView.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(ProductViewRowBound);
    }

    protected void ProductViewRowBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string hyperLink = e.Row.Cells[1].Text;
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Test";
            //HyperLink link = new HyperLink;
        }
    }
}
```

ASPX File:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Maintenance.aspx.cs" Inherits="Maintenance" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <div style="overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:scroll; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
        <asp:GridView ID="ProductView" runat="server" Height="299px" Width="578px" AllowPaging="True" HorizontalAlign="Center"
            OnRowDataBoundEvent="ProductViewRowBound" style="table-layout:auto">
            <HeaderStyle Width="300px" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Why is my RowDataBoundEvent not running and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `OnRowDataBoundEvent` does not exist. It should be `OnRowDataBound` in the GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="ProductView" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="ProductViewRowBound">
```

Next you are binding the correct method to the GridView from code behind, but AFTER you bind data to the GridView. So it will not work when you bind `productAdapter.GetData()`.

So either set the correct event name in the GridView aspx or move the method binding above `ProductView.DataBind();`

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not catch that! Everything is working as intended. I can't believe I missed it. Thanks again for the help!